# regular expresssion to match something and not match something

Tags: regex, nginx

I want an nginx location directive that would match all urls with "xyz" and not match ".php"

I tried this

```
location ~* /(.*)xyz/(.*)(?!\.php)(.*)$ {}
```

but for example it always seem to match both /xyz/1 and /xyz/1.php but it should have matched only /xyz/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, we finally came up with this

```
location ~* ^/xyz([^.]*)/([^.]*)$ {
            rewrite  ^/xyz([^.]*)/([^.]*)$ /xyz$1/index.php/$2 last;
}
```

and it works.

Answer (score 2):

You should be more specific about the begin and end of the location. If `.php` should not appear at the end of the location, put `$` in the look-ahead assertion:

```
location ~* /(.*)xyz/(.*)(?!.*\.php$)(.*)$ {}
```

And if `xyz` should be a proper path segment and the first path segment (so it must start with `/xyz/`), use this:

```
location ~* ^/xyz/(?!.*\.php$)(.*)$ {}
```

Comment: I personally assume, given the (.*) at the end, that .php might end up with something else (parameters probably) after it. Yet the ^ and $ markers are often forgotten and may solve a lot of trouble when applicable. :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do this without a separate regex checking to make sure that ".php" is absent. The problem is that constructs like `.*` will swallow up enough characters to make sure that your negative lookahead never applies.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as Michael said, though .*? (note the '?') will make the search non-greedy and it could work.

...Or, you could try (rather hackish):

```
[^.][^p][^h][^p]
```

Might works, might not... It definately is sort of a hack.

Comment: This is difficult to read, debug and would require quite a bit of comment if left in application code. I think hacks should be reserved only for when there are no other solutions, and the solution is easy here.

Comment: This is wrong. It fails when at least one of the four character classes cannot be matched. But it should only fail if all of them cannot be matched.

Comment: I think you're mixing up `[^a][^b]` with `[^ab]`

Answer (score 1):

This one is simple, yet it can be tough to see. The second (.*) in the regex is "greedy", hence, it will capture everything including the ".php" so, to the parser's "eyes" there is no ".php" after it (it's already passed) and the result is a match. :(

Just make the second .* lazy by changing it to .*? and it will solve your problem :

```
location ~* /(.*)xyz/(.*?)(?!\.php)(.*)$ {}
```

I suggest you read [this article](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), it explains it in a much better way than I. :D